# What is Custom Web Object

Tags: html, qtp

I'm working in Test Automation of web application and I come across "Custom Objects" which the Automation tool can't recognize.

I would like to understand technically what does custom object means, is it something like an object not designed using HTML code.

Could anyone please clarify me. Thank you.

Comment: Where did you come across the phrase _Custom Objects_? What are the symptoms that you are encountering?

Answer (score 0):

Objects which are not developed in the same technology as the application under test are custom objects

or eg, when the application is developed using Java EE stack , for some reasons there might be need to develop one of the objects(say calendar object) in C# which makes this a custom objecy

Hope this helped